# Pick one: Vaccines or Anti-Vaccination?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a currently a [vaccines](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vaccines) and [anti-vaccination](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-vaccination). It seems useless to have both. Which one should be used?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The subject of those questions is [vaccines](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vaccines). Saying [anti-vaccination](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-vaccination) doesn't suggest a **different subject**; It only asserts a *position* on the issue, which should be avoided.

Otherwise, the whole tagging structure would become prohibitive. For every tag like:

- [evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution), [homeopathy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homeopathy), and [climate-change](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change)

… are you really going to create a set of contra-tags?

- [anti-evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anti-evolution), [homeopathy-fallacies](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homeopathy-fallacies), and [climate-change-myth](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate-change-myth)

The tags should indicate the subject of the debate, nothing more. You don't need a separate flag for each side of the argument.