# *-denialism tags

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pick one: Vaccines or Anti-Vaccination?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28/pick-one-vaccines-or-anti-vaccination)

We now have the [aids-denialists](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aids-denialists) tag on some questions. The same questions also have the [aids](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aids) tag.

Essentially, we only need one of the two tags. Anything aids-related discussed here is bound to be about aids denialism.

I propose to **generally** ban denialism tags for all topics. We can always state the topic in a positive way instead of using the denialists label.

Do you agree?

Comment: @Borror I remembered we had something like that before, I didn't remember it was essentially exactly the same question. So we have our answer already, I'll also vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the term "denial" except for genocide denial. Many genocide deniers know the genocide took place, want it to happen again, and try to make it more likely to happen again by pretending it didn't happen in the first place. By contrast, people who promote disbelief in other phenomenon actually think it didn't happen.

Comment: Those still should be tagges [tag:genocide], not with denialism

Comment: @Fabian: I'm pretty sure he was just ranting, not suggesting that those question should be tagged with [genocide-denialism].