# Should we burninate the alternative-medicine tag?

Tags: discussion

Given that the very reason for it being called "alternative" medicine rather than just medicine is because it doesn't work, it seems like a waste of time having this rubbish polluting our site.

Thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do we need an alt-medicine and a medicine tag?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/do-we-need-an-alt-medicine-and-a-medicine-tag)

Answer (score 0):

There's certainly a space for [alternative-medicine](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternative-medicine). Alternative medicine is

- medicine that has been shown not to work

but also

- medicine that has not been shown to work

There's plenty of substances which are *claimed* to work, or that are openly called "*alternative*" by their proponent (alternative to Big Pharma™).

As such, we should have a tag group these questions, which are not about medical science (medicine that has been shown to work).

See also: [Do we need an alt-medicine and a medicine tag?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/do-we-need-an-alt-medicine-and-a-medicine-tag)

Hat tip to [Tim Minchin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HhGuXCuDb1U) for the alliteration.